# PHP & MySQLi using prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, methods, mysqli

I want to use the established connection using singleton design pattern.
I need help on how to achieve this because I can't query some data

db.config.php:

```
define ('HOST','localhost');
define ('USER','garodamas_mon');
define ('PASSWORD','r0d4m45');
define ('DATABASE','garodamas_cashrcv');

class Database{
    private $DBH;
    private static $singleton;
    protected function __construct(){
        $this->DBH=new mysqli(HOST,USER,PASSWORD,DATABASE);
    }
    public static function instance(){
        if (!(self::$singleton instanceof self)) {
            self::$singleton = new self();
        }
        return self::$singleton;
    }
    public static function get(){
        return self::instance()->DBH;
    }
    private function __wake(){}
    private function __clone(){}
}
```

and loginmodel.php:

```
require_once '../db.config.php';

$db = DATABASE::getInstance();
 $mysqli = $db->getConnection(); 
    $sql_query = "SELECT user_name FROM mst_user";
    $result = $mysqli->query($sql_query);
```

and the error message is,

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::getInstance() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SOBCASHIER\resources\templates\loginmodel.php on line 5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `getInstance` method - the method you defined is called `instance`:

```
$db = DATABASE::instance();
```